# How do I make it so when I rotate my model using the numpad it stays in orthographic instead of perspective by default?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, settings

I'd like for my numpad rotations to be in orthographic instead of perspective.

Comment: See what you have set in Edit > Preferences > Navigation tab, Orbit & Pan > Auto Perspective. Default is checked.

Comment: use numpad 5 while being in perspective, it should stay ortho after that.